# XMLHttpRequest2 uploading files to api

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to understand what happens in the XMLHttpRequest2 request when using it like this:

xhr.send(file)

What is the flow here? Does it first upload the temp data somewhere and then post it? In my experiance withit the request is only sent when the file has reached 100% upload (upload to where??)

Im running into issues that I cannot find the reasons for.

My upload works well with files like 20mb size, but as soon as they get more like 50mb plus it fails with a Bad Request and the server never gets the the request from my application.

This my code, following the html5rocks tutorial:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "foo url goes here");
xhr.send(file);
```

As I said, this works with smaller files, but failes and never reaches the server with larger ones like 50mb.

this also does not work with a normal AJAX post, same issue.

Im posing to a WCF rest service.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ajax upload form</title>
  <script src="app/js/lib/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(':button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myurl',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
    function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}

  })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you say that the failure only occurs with large requests, I'd guess this is a server-side configuration problem and that your server connection is timing out or has a hard request size limit.

Comment: By "Bar Request", do you see a "400 Bad Request" response from the server, or are you referring to a client-side JavaScript error?